# How to click on radio button which is on Popup using Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I m automating a page where there is a popup and on that there is radio button and a submit button, when i click on radio button my test fail giving error that hidden object cannot be performed action like click but its visible (not hidden) where as when i click on submit button on same popup is click. i have checked its properties but there is nothing which i can change it just have simple id,name,value which is changing dynamicly and for that i have even used regex 
please help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is another radio button on the page with similar properties. Is this a recorded object? Is the popup window listed as the parent?

Can you post the Regex you are using, the control's properties, and the properties of the popup window?

Comment: Hey thanks, but I figure out that problem, it was due to change of TagInstance Propertie so i used regex there and its now working

Answer (score 0):

if your are using IE whose version is > 9.0.19 then there was a patch release by Microsoft to overcome this issue

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx

Comment: You could include the link to it